# How to access current bg image?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to create a button that changes my UIView's background image every time it is hit. Basically I have 3 images in an array that I want to cycle next to each time "Change BG" is pressed.

I'm currently using `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image.png"]];` in my viewDidLoad to first set my bg.

The question is, when my "Change BG" button is pressed, how to I figure out what the current BG is set to? I've tried using an if statement like this:

```
if(self.view.backgroundColor == [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image.png"]])
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I also tried creating a local variable UIColor *bg = self.view.backgroundColor and then comparing that to `bg == [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image.png"]];` but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to store current background image's info to a property. (UIImage, NSString, or just a tag), so that later when you pressed the button, you can know current which is current bg image.

Bonny's answer works correctly, but I don't recommend you do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

what about using tag .

```
#define FirstTag 1
#define SecondTag 2
#define ThirdTag 3
```

when change the first bg image.
set `self.view.tag = FirstTag` and so on.

when pressed the button , just figure out the tag `if (self.view.tag == FirstTag)`...